# Creating an array of objects from an object, where key = string, value = array of strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, sorting, pagination, filtering

Let's say I have an object looking like this `obj = {"column1": ["value1", "value"], "column2": ["value3", "value4"]}`. Am I able to convert that object to a list of objects looking like this using vanilla javascript: `arr = [{"column1": "value1", "column2": "value3"}, {"column1": "value2", "column2": "value4"}]`.

I'm trying to create a table in html. Using obj in itself will work to create a table, but when introducing things like pagination, filtering and sorting, it seems kind of difficult to have an object like that.

```
function generateTableHead(table, obj, test2) {
    let thead = table.createTHead();
    let row = thead.insertRow();
    for (let key in obj) {
        let th = document.createElement("th");
        let text = document.createTextNode(key);
        th.appendChild(text);
        row.appendChild(th);
    }
}
function generateCells(table, obj) {
    var length = (<string[]>Object.values(obj)[0]).length;
    var tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
    table.appendChild(tbody);
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        let row = tbody.insertRow();
        for (let key in obj) {
            if (obj[key].length <= i) {
                break;
            }
            let cell = row.insertCell();
            let text = document.createTextNode(obj[key][i]);
            cell.append(text);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming every column is the same length, then you can create an empty object, go through each column add the column/value pair with the value's index as the key in the new object, then use `Object.values()` to convert the object into an array. Like this:

```js
obj = {"column1": ["value1", "value"], "column2": ["value3", "value4"]};

let arr = {};
for (const col in obj) {
  obj[col].forEach((el, i) => {
    if (!arr[i]) arr[i] = {};
    arr[i][col] = el;
  });
}
arr = Object.values(arr);
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Oh wow, thank you for the fast answer! This is exactly what I'm looking for.